# Outputting hyperlinks to outlook

Tags: python

I am trying to do the following,but the data finally that gets feeded to outlook is messedup,please look at the pastie links below for input,output and the code

1.read data from an xml using minidom 
2.and if there are hyperlinks ,am replacing with a regex to add ahref atribute
3.Outputting the data to outlook

```
INPUT/Output:-
http://pastie.org/5408694
```

My code:-

http://pastie.org/5408681

```
# Import package to access Outlook
import win32com.client
import re
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
resultslis=[]

def getsanityresults(xmlfile):
  dom = minidom.parse(xmlfile)
  data=dom.getElementsByTagName('Sanity_Results')
  textnode = data[0].childNodes[0]
  testresults=textnode.data
  for line in testresults.splitlines():
    line = line.strip('\r,\n')
    line = re.sub(r'(http://[^\s]+|//[^\s]+|\\\\[^\s]+)', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', line)
    print line     
    resultslis.append(line)
  return resultslis

def main ():
  file = open('results.xml','r')
  sanityresults=getsanityresults(file)
  print sanityresults
  msg_body=("<HTML><head></head>"
        "<body> <font face = \"Calibri\" <br>"
          "<font face = \"Calibri\"%s<br><br>"

        "</body></html>"
        ) % (sanityresults)

  olMailItem = 0x0
  obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
  newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  newMail.HTMLBody = msg_body
  newMail.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Please copy the code here, otherwise the question won't make sense for future visitors when the pastie page goes down.

Comment: If I paste here,indentation is getting messedup..how to fix it?

Comment: @user: Indent code with four spaces.

Comment: Or select the code and click on the curly braces pair in the buttons above the text field. They indent the selection automatically.

Comment: Thanks,I pasted teh code

Comment: may be I should not put in a list..I actually want to just replace the line..any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question.following change to subroutine worked

```
def getsanityresults(xmlfile):
    testresult=[]
    dom = minidom.parse(xmlfile)
    data=dom.getElementsByTagName('Sanity_Results')
    textnode = data[0].childNodes[0]
    testresults=textnode.data
    for line in testresults.splitlines():
        line = line.strip('\r,\n')
        line = re.sub(r'(http://[^\s]+|//[^\s]+|\\\\[^\s]+)', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', line)
        testresult.append(line) 
    return '<br>'.join(testresult)
```